# Installing GCC<8 in anaconda environment

Tags: gcc, anaconda

Is it possible to install gcc versions earlier than 8 in anaconda environment?

I have tried installing it with `conda install gcc_linux-64==7.5.0`. This successfully installs but `which gcc` and `gcc --version` keeps pointing to the global gcc (at /usr/bin/gcc)

Anaconda's official page (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gcc) proposes `conda install conda-forge::gcc` but that dose not even install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conda install -c anaconda gcc\_linux-64 not being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284298/conda-install-c-anaconda-gcc-linux-64-not-being-used)

Comment: See linked dup and https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html By design, conda installed compilers have a prefix instead of sharing the same binary names with the system-wide versions